# HAProxy keeps setting X-Forwarded-Proto header to http instead of https on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, ssl, openshift, haproxy

I am sending ssl traffic to a scalable app on OpenShift, but oddly enough, HAProxy keeps setting the X-Forwarded-Proto header to http instead of https, triggering the express middleware "express-sslify" to cause a "to many redirects" error. The snippet below is from florianheinemann's express-sslify, to demonstrate how an incorrect header value causes a 301 loop.

```
var enforceHTTPS = function(options) {

    ...

    // First, check if directly requested via https
    var isHttps = req.secure;

    // Second, if the request headers can be trusted (e.g. because they are send
    // by a proxy), check if x-forward-proto is set to https
    if(!isHttps && options.trustProtoHeader) {
        isHttps = ((req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] || '').substring(0,5) === 'https');
    }

    ...

    if(isHttps) {
        next();
    } else {
        // Only redirect GET methods
        if(req.method === "GET" || req.method === 'HEAD') {
            res.redirect(301, "https://" + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl);
        } else {
            res.status(403).send("Please use HTTPS when submitting data to this server.");
        }
    }
};
```

};

In my own code, I'm using the module with the trustProtoHeader option: `app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }))`. HAProxy is configured by OpenShift, although I've also tried their template on [https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/images/router/haproxy/conf/haproxy-config.template][1].

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Show your HAProxy configuration.  HAProxy, itself, has no internal concept of `X-Forwarded-Proto`, so if it is adding that option at all, that's going to be because of its configuration, so, by logical extension, it has to be configured incorrectly for your environment or you would not see incorrecr behavior.  Or `options.trustProtoHeader` isn't set to true, of course.

Comment: Hi, I've posted a gist with the HAProxy config as it was stored on the gear.
[link] https://gist.github.com/sebsylvester/82f78bdc7f724bc2e08911e405c93bec . I am not an expert in HAProxy but I will delve in the docs to learn more about it. I'm positive that it is not a problem with express-sslify, because I've tried to solve it without the module as well, to no avail.

Comment: I don't see anything here similar to `http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http if ...` (newer style) or `reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http if ...` (older style) so I don't believe it's possible that HAProxy is doing anything with this header at all.  This file as written would only work on versions before 1.5 (GA is 1.6) but that isn't going to be a factor on what you are seeing.  But for ultimate confirmation, capture some packets with a tool like `tshark`.  Packet traces don't lie or leave you guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I discovered that it's more a custom domain-issue than HAProxy. It turns out that when I send ssl traffic directly to the OpenShift gear, the "x-forwarded-proto" header is indeed https. But when secure traffic goes through Cloudflare (that I use for DNS and caching), it's always http. The SO question should have been, how to redirect http to https on OpenShift when using a custom domain.

Comment: So, if anyone else comes here because of this, the problem can be fixed by setting the CloudFlare Crypto SSL setting to "Full" or "Full (Strict)".

If that option is set to Flexible, CloudFlare turns HTTPS requests into HTTP, and that is why X-Forwarded-Proto was set to http by OpenShift.